# Application running in docker container is not accessible through container-IP

Tags: docker, containers

I am new to Docker, please help me to resolve my issue.

I have installed docker on Windows 8, ran the container of image nginx.

But I am not able to access it by it's container IP, which is obtained by `docker container inspect <container_id>`.

I am trying to access it on the same machine on which docker is installed. I think it is supposed to access within the machine without exposing the port.

Comment: The container-private IP address are unreachable from Windows hosts (and in fact from almost all environments).  You need a `docker run -p` option to make them accessible.

Comment: see: https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to access it without exposing the port.

The container ip can be used within an internal docker network for container to container connectivity. Expose the port by running `docker run` with the `-p` flag, and specify the source and target port, or `-P` to expose *all*.